Convert TS to JS return " x is not a constructor "
Hello every body i need some help please this is the code i want to convert to NODE JS
I have a ts file i don't want change in my source file but in my js files just down i try to change import :
Current ts file
import Raydium from './Raydium'; //Ts file

const swap = async () => {
    const raydiumConnect = new Raydium(HTTP_URL, walletkey);
}
/// WORK OK
 

This is what is tried with js file:
const Raydium = require('./Raydium');

const swap = async () => {
  const raydiumConnect = new Raydium(HTTP_URL, walletkey);
}
//ERROR : Raydium is not a constructor

I dont understand what is the problem because it work with others lines .. but not for raydium

Check the Export in Raydium.ts:
If Raydium.ts uses export default:

export default class Raydium {

}
 In this case, the correct JavaScript import would be:

const Raydium = require('./Raydium').default;
const swap = async () => {
const raydiumConnect = new Raydium(HTTP_URL, walletkey);
};



If Raydium.ts uses a named export:

export class Raydium {

}
 Then, the correct JavaScript import would be:

 const { Raydium } = require('./Raydium');
 const swap = async () => {
 const raydiumConnect = new Raydium(HTTP_URL, walletkey);
};

Because of differences in how exports are handled in JavaScript after transpilation, the error "Raydium is not a constructor" can arise. You can fix this by changing how you import Raydium in your JS file depending on whether it's a named export or a default.
Read more about it here => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Thanks a lot for your answer !!
